# setting options when using a ssh socks5 proxy

Tags: proxy, ssh, socks

My ssh socks5 proxy starts to hang after a while running and I'm thinking it probably has something to do with the proxy sockets staying alive for much longer than needed.  I've searched and searched for options to use (using ssh -O) but there isn't much out there.

I'm setting up my proxy like this:

```
ssh -D9090 talcolm@a.proxyserver.com
```

Can someone point me to a resource that details options I can pass to an ssh socks5 proxy?  I think I basically want to lower the socket timeout the proxy uses.  It would also be nice to see what else I can fiddle with to try and get my proxy tuned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea about your question, but why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: My mistake, was just a typo, fixed now.